# Number of semi-standard tableau

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of semi-standard tableau (weakly increasing on rows and strictly increasing on columns) for the partition $2n=n+n$ with entries $\{1,2, \cdots ,n\}$ such that each $i$ appears exactly twice? I guess it has something to do with two copies of a irreducible representation of the general linear group $GL_n$ and I have tried computing this using Hook length formula but failed subsequently. And, is there a way to get all of them?

Comment: This is the multiplicity of the irreducible $GL_n$ module with the highest weight $n\omega_2$ in the $n$-th tensor power of the irreducible with the highest weight $2\omega_1$ (the symmetric square of the standard representation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the coefficient of $(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^2$ in the schur polynomial associated to the partition $(n,n)$. By Jacobi-Trudi this can be written in terms of the complete homogeneous symmetric functions as
$$s_{(n,n)}=\begin{vmatrix} h_n & h_{n+1} \\ h_{n-1} & h_n\end{vmatrix}.$$
From here you can find that this quantity is the coefficient of $t^n$ in $(1-t)(1+t+t^2)^n$. These numbers are called [Riordan numbers](https://oeis.org/A005043). Their generating function is given by
$$\frac{2}{1+x+\sqrt{1-2x-3x^2}},$$
and they satisfy several recurrence relations that you can find in that OEIS link.

Comment: Thanks, for making the life simple. Is there any way to get all of them starting from the tableau (1,2,...,n)(1,2,...,n) ? I mean applying some permutation on this tableau.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of calculation you have in mind. A way of doing this without using symmetric functions is to notice that your tableaux correspond to Dyck paths of length $2n$ with no peaks at odd level. You can work out the recurrence relations straight from this, however some amount of work is unavoidable given that the final formula is "not too simple".

Comment: Okay. What is the number of SSYT for the partition $2kn=kn+kn$ with entries $\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ such that each $i$ appear exactly $2k$ times. Is it the coefficient of $t^n$ in $(1-t)(1+t+ \cdots +t^{2k})^n$ ?

Comment: @Harry, almost! It's the coefficient of $t^{kn}$ in $(1-t)(1+t+\cdots+t^{2k})^n$.